# Is there any Conditional IF like operator in Apache PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Actually I am writing PIG Script and want to execute some set of statements if one of the condition is satisfied.

I have set one variable and checking for some value of that variable. Suppose

```
if flag==0 then
  A = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage() as (f1:int, ....);
  B = ...;
  C = ....;
else 
  again some Pig Latin statements
```

Can I do this in PIG Script? If yes, then how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I came across conditional operator in Pig Latin like (a == b ? c1 : c2);. But How can I insert bulk of Pig Statements in between that?

Comment: Bhavesh, You need to write a wrapper for that The recommended
approach for writing programs that have conditional logic or
loop constructs is to embed Pig Latin in another language like Python,
JavaScript or Java, and manage the control flow from there.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, Pig does offer an if-then-else construction, *but it is not used in the way you're asking*.

Pig's if-then-else [is an arithmetic operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators+and+More) invoked with the shorthand "condition ? true_value : false_value" as part of an expression, such as:

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE f2, (f2==1?1:COUNT(B));
```

You have to already have loaded the table A to do this.  To execute control flow around entire Pig statements you'll need something like [oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/), as suggested by Fakrudeen.

Comment: This works for conditions based on the data being processed, but not conditions/flags based on external parameters.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Python wrapper around your Pig script. See [Embedded Pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cont.html#embed-python) in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Pig is data flow language not control flow.
Only construct which comes close is  PIG [split](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#SPLIT), but it is very limited.

You can use [oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/) and its [decision](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node) construct with two pig scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **UDF** (say, in Java) and then embed that into your **PIG script**. You will need to 'register' the jar file that you generate after writing the **UDF**.

//(something like this), say your Java `UDF class` is `UDFCondition`  & the generated **jar** file is **PigUDFCondition.jar**, then in your `PIG Code`

register **PigUDFCondition.jar**

```
X = foreach A generate UDFCondition(..flag...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CASE Statement available from version 0.12 onwards.

Comment: And how would this help? Could you extend your answer by an example?