# How to Implement IF ELSE control logic in PIG Script

Tags: apache-pig

We have requirement of executing script based on Condition like

IF (true)
//execute  this statement
ELSE
//execute this statement

I heard IF else is not present but it can be implement using "?". Any sample around using of trinary operator and execute pig query based on condition

Comment: Its been anwered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669522/is-there-any-conditional-if-like-operator-in-apache-pig

Answer (score 0):

You should use BinCond for that purpose.

For example:

```
A = LOAD 'your_data' USING PigStorage() AS (name:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name, ( name == 'Bieber'? 1: 0) AS canadian_stars;
```

What we do is check if there is a string matches 'Bieber' in charraray name  if yes we assign value 1, else 0.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Madbitloman, Basically I'm looking for Individual statement just like IF else . I want to make use of IF else out side projection operation not within select project columns.

Comment: the simplest way probably is to use bash and split your pig script

Comment: can u plz help with a sample or URL for reference